# Cannot remove pagination and add sorting indicators in v-data-table in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vite

I am porting an old vue2 project to vue3 my project is setup on vite and I am using v-data-table from vuetify labs at the moment. I am unable to remove pagination and the default sorting indicators on the data table headers are not visible. Like the one's [that appear here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/basics/) on hover

This is my vdatatable component.

```
 <v-card-title>Asks</v-card-title>
            <div class="table-container">
            <v-data-table
              dense
              :sort-by="sortBy"
              :headers="asksHeaders"
              :items="marketdata.asks"
              :rows-per-page="-1"
              options="disablePagination"
              class="elevation-1"
            >
              <template v-slot:column.price="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Price ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.maxvolume="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Amount ({{wallets.base.ticker }})
              </template>

              <template v-slot:column.relamount="{ header }">
                <!-- {{ header.text.toUpperCase() }} -->
                Total ({{wallets.rel.ticker }})
              </template>

              <!-- Rounding from https://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/ -->
              <!-- Better to move to computed function for maintainability/non-repetitive -->
              <template v-slot:item.price="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.price2="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price) }}
  <!-- Remaining code -->

<!--
better implementation handled in parent component on load of orders, then promise to set flag
                <v-chip v-if="hasMyOrder(item.price)" color="purple" dark>me</v-chip>
-->
                <v-chip v-if="item.myOrder" x-small color="purple" dark>*</v-chip>
              </template> 

              <template v-slot:item.maxvolume="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.maxvolume) }}
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.relamount="{ item }">
                {{ roundedPrice(item.columns.price * item.columns.maxvolume) }}
              </template>
              <template v-slot:bottom></template>
            </v-data-table>
            </div>


<script>
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

export default {
  name: "MarketData",
  props: ['wallets', 'marketdata', 'myOrdersThisMarket'],
  components: {
    VDataTable
  },
```

These are my versions:

```
{
  "name": "mm2v3",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vite preview",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "dev": "vite",
    "host": "vite --host",
    "format": "prettier --write src/",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "pinia": "^2.0.32",
    "qrcode.vue": "^3.3.4",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.2.47",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6",
    "vuetify": "npm:@vuetify/nightly@next",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.9.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "vite": "^4.1.4",
    "vite-plugin-vuetify": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8"
  }
}
```

[Complete code here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNrtWm1v2zgS/is847a2dyO5TQ+4hS8J2qQtDji0Xez1Dgs0/UBLdKxGEgWR8guy+e/7DElJlC0nbrMpUGADBJbJeZ/h8CHljzeDl0URLisxmA5OtMiKlGtxdpkzdrIMIl7GLOPrYJXEenF6OWieLwcsSrlSNLYOeKUlRmSl0yQXsWE3ArSU6YyXbA6pLBa5EiySqSzBluRxcgUuR+yTBzrRqTXCTamC541CVc0WgsdJfgXul1pmSfTq9W9MlrEo2UzK65MJ0beCJ/skn8TJshE7T8U6uCrlKngGuScTzPm2RYukaH3mwTGFwPmyWiRaeAFgL6I0ia4xU4p5KdTiLS+vhR6NPXeN0CSSOUvFXJ9lcRIoUS5FGRRppchmmjz71QrwfSFL6hC3rtUj5BJ458ZK0hpzzUOurpUfa985Y0nKN7DeGzOjFBOWxSy96sw0xeHi+RLSjWXt0Ba5H2jNZ6kI4JzmCFbZiUkjnawODOX2JLOFtDs8VbLUwWxDJYKn883loIeISkeUZAfF5N/2Wy8lcprZZG+FsYcWZaOCgpLHrwR4qIZ2yWShE5mTzDhR5Nsv/CrJOQ32kdcBE6lYGqI+qTvBQ/jqdYxCUKnUU9RpleVhUSYRGXfDbBDYbU/s6e8XImSjm5sVT1OhVViKNNSoaOK5HfdonHit43CD0E6W9HSQUSd/CwJ2U5OFWqx1qOX/CkT9gisxGsM0FgS9vC8zWeXa92gGlsdwCZHiRtlju/RBap7+mTkiW36F5dRY2byUGVtoXajpZLJarcLPPLpOMylLEUYym+RSCzUpHXmQ5MFnvuQqKpNCT/pNNgrOhdYwUEuWyaWgT0grKo2eOa/yiIqczWWJTScx7YHPkjTRG+jLg1IUAs0lAV+/gu2U0AL2ip6+7k0FsmC8EbEp/pHhtTlVVgYl4+Fl0tp0/HhG1dkUFEZKZyRjF7R9xJf5zKYmgb0iE4i+ScaC53GK7CQ5K3iJYZMwmdMT7V2Sx0zO7earjpheCBCieBJs9ciuEpo2/6ueyLgt1e1VC67ebt6TFOul9c7bY4uqhGEYiNGOzzLh7YR7VsiWBiM2szogZh2oDCunX36fOLTaH2ulffN9Ffk1xdFtil9fH42cP7Fwu93tgbXLfjQSegzuk3evD/d6MJMaYBHIbi8TpbcFHtsYpoMIa3JCSD6SwtAWlPL5Os8WqYlUibN36INVaZYXQQxaOUAIMHITdlgWxw0oKNLguRd6hDtLYixVE+3/FiW2lFcEWewobSRv7ZPb3C3JFIy1iH5+ZR7B/oNLy8lkcdyUzB64OUviR4Sb55D+vcBNB/QIFzqkRyaVFTrNneCUIviF4NQGfR/tfej0MXDkQ/DNt8KgBAS/DWL7diD0m+Hqv0DodwFCyek3cGiRXC1S/GuKbrZpUNuH96/es1zAfw7wBjXTqkrwpSz5hs0EYiEYbkaqgvhmG0tDkBB3Rx9KKptlIlbQ9KUheXQMvA/W9sDZvyDqgZnb6ph19noVHoZQ2aSLBF1ke1Fga/Du/MEu9GPsB3hANfhQy74PfEooox+f1pAMXzo+nNiObGiwDIGVGF8nUtn+PjTPQ2/yhv2fkOcH8pHdOircUOtkvpmkfKYm7Tz4iFOsDWcs5rxKIcF6kPNMTNnQXr4Sy/DITuCAij2FfRy6bWt4xIYtkDLf7CJUHxaJsvzDT465aRiQ0GDn1iJHdes+SeC03VawmzY8pdBVmbffIRp+mPbLhrWpBpg7Y7aGNcc2+yrhqbyCBo48+Tx3TXIYsxQXMskpCrVj9GcDcs5TnpMZN4wW+5Q9PYK1KT4bv4wB1PpbIhhnqeih9YPZXoHnp8MOOy+Kd/syZKJRKawHUZaSXO+YaQE3Bm/YtcDn8KPR9wnazJ6GkVioCPp8Lu/CF6z+SvFyYByjMwVkOAwKp8a+YUYW9tEcJHR5vz1H1lEpTBGhyo87/Vl7jbldPj80sKgxooaNFGSYsaXZyWsaUTfEvhyH1cgZX0xJeKCR0xzwu3L8KHonk+8oiueInkPg+2LY7mv7g3iB91D4j0S6N4R7UtGG0IGVejITeiFjv5l0XhrtaR4IL1pT+HeRJXqEtBmOwDaxYbN1tgbI2WcR6ZeE6M43/xEb6GvlYrIjGi0ALd4Qs1OsvHbmvRETwlNluEJgw9c8WoxaYZjrCIOlVlRYVGpBXB9B8snb3v2DgmuKjmXXjxaE+Q44HOhpreVQkHabeTjH68fRmp2esbW7jDo9tT1rJ3b1Z4R7EBwR9uQD9wtKpiJEvx0Zpa67sZ/YkF1Y1jYvkwn6VEI3AiltRrG5oPUm6/SqhVzh3aZ7fWiGes6OdO3qzbRnMF/fSpbX5lCFjcHsSt6cjVKzASLnZoRIqSn7lELp5iiwX4J5UVaLMeTnG9MGjq0TtWRDd8QAbWnycjD+1x0yDfI4QCbR7ZFpeYW+eP2bmf2KkDbS7sz4G9y7qwUOVFupb4rJHTi9VR9hO76wO+WeFe/XtLeFh6nIr/BKfmetdHBrnyRX+Wfd5eom31XZDEed0VuuF6ERZZcZrm2fiZ/HwOz0gauCN8laxKOfx/6K3jWm93bRdzWVK7xHPjKHVNzwdexFNdx5u/nkzsvLbmPrpURd3XiHyDuVnbLhO2kA6/33piB+2lImczbqNMbeVYNORHlDi0L9/P77XQx2SfgMLfVWE3ZZ7TW2J3GHGetKj50BGT55cp+lHvVeMylDqAS0GRRDvdq3tRI06NjG2IgfsdmYapm7hh6wmX3yCccfn37aHSWlVHbQisrr0Wqsv1Or0wWtTv9hWpsqwW2EEm/wOk3TQrDujyHNG28t7ByN25ruiula2i+H/bR9xBx9mSHUBo47rvpf7llG9sHrIKZ14k6plOuQeSvs3jW231lHUvePMXWvp175weLGgGcd4w9cMIwOyA9aal2ggWH8fqk+MZ8ovXEn/XDrRUatE7/Hwo9PpuTWD25zwq1mOUf2gvWU0W+zzLAV7MQNjgb2tA3IWISflczx+y8jELdQZgKvEprN6XKA4zd9xyWYu46N4hxssUiTZRnmQk/yIpu8ANmkxBaWZCKIZfbiefg8/AcuCJT2h0OhsmBGP5nBffNnKHIBMGrolH+AKkdpNPzTanBDuN+YKVKxI3rifmCFewzAQbpiO8yjLTbfq62pHc9c4G8Rb/wyDK2rG+pImTC7U9QDXTbCSBLw+u3g9mhg7IRmwzD49AcEYNts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Removing the pagination

As shown in the ["External Pagination" example in the Vuetify 3 docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/pagination/#external-pagination), you can change the pagination of a data table by overriding the content of the `"bottom"` slot. By overriding the slot but not providing any content, you can effectively remove the pagination.

#### Keeping the default sorting mechanism

Based on your example code, you're already overriding the headers slot for each column, which would be why the default sorting controls are not appearing [[docs]](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/headers/#column-slot). If you still want to keep the default sorting controls, you'll need to what the docs state and re-implement that sorting functionality. There's [an example of how to do this in the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/headers/#headers-slot) as well, although it on re-implements the "click" part of the functionality, not the "hover" part.

#### Putting it all together

You can see an example that implements that using the `<v-hover>` component and some inline styling here: [[Vuetify playground link]](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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). The first, second, and third headers in the example have been overridden, and the fourth and fifth headers have been left with the default.

This approach would probably benefit from a custom component to abstract away the logic for the sort icon, otherwise that template will get verbose quickly.

Comment: I don't want to remove sorting indicators in fact the sorting indicators do not appear for my I want them to appear. The thing is I am porting an old vue2 project to vue3 I c+p most of the things the front-end works fine but some components are a headache

Comment: Ah, I misread your original question. You would only need to overload the "bottom" slot to make the pagination go away. If you're still not able to see the sorting feature, please update your question with the version of Vuetify you're using and some example code to show how you're using the <v-data-table> component.

Comment: Done check my question

Comment: Fixed now thanks, however the sorting indicators don't appear here is the link to what I am referring to check the data table labelled market data v3dev.komodefi.com:17077/traderview/kmd/btc

Comment: Based on your example code in the question, you're already overriding the header slot per-column, which is why the default sorting is gone. See my updated answer for a more extensive solution.

Comment: Can you post the example in playground according to my example I have a different setting in my scenario.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the example to override specific header slots instead of the general header slot.

Comment: IDK but does not work for me I have updated my question with a link to complete code. However still thanks for helping me fix my pagination issue. Don't wanna bother much but if you can help thanks